# Inject inaccessible properties using Guice

Tags: java, servlets, guice, inject

How can I inject a property to a class I don't have access to using Guice? I only have access to the .jar that contains that class.

Also, I need the injected property to be available from the start of a Web Application (I suppose I can do this with a Servlet though).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Provider`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) class. You can have something like this (where `Foo` is the 3rd party bean):

```
public class FooProvider implements Provider<Foo> {
    public Foo get() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, take a look at [guice-xml](https://code.google.com/p/guice-xml-config/), but I don't know how stable and up-to-date it is.)